# Facing 2 Min threshold issue (2-minute timeout exception) in the Async plugin in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

In one of our CRM online environment, we have an asynchronous plugin which is deleting a NOTE(annotation) record by using the GUID of the notes.

This plugin is crashing due to the 2-minute timeout error which ideally should not be happened.

Can anybody share the possible reason behind this behavior?

Any help would much be appreciated.

Comment: Is it deleting a single note or a set of notes? Posting the code may help...

Comment: I think if you are working under a 365 online enviroment you share the resources of the asynchronous service, so, if this service doesn't have resources for you, the plugin will wait and eventually will throw the 2 minutes exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation on plugins and custom workflow assemblies running in the sandbox environment.

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/create-own-actions#watch-out-for-long-running-actions

As advised by the article above, use an external application to perform the action. Create a console application to delete the notes.